# What is a quasibound state and how is it different from a bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, definition, stability, quantum-states

What is a **quasibound** state and how is it different from a bound state?

I have read this term in nuclear physics in the context of compound nucleus formation. A compound nucleus $C$ is formed by the absorption of a projectile 'a' (say a nucleon) by a target nucleus which is called a quasibound state.

The current answer by @Paul defines a quasibound state as a metastable state around a local minimum. But how can the nuclear potential, which is of Woods-Saxon type, have quasibound states? It does not seem to have a local minimum like the one shown below.

Answer (score 5):

A quasibound state is a state that can exist in a local minimum, which does not necessarily correspond to the global minimum. Quantum tunneling then limits the lifetime of these states. More general, it corresponds to a resonant state in a potential through which the wave function can tunnel. In the figure below, curve (a) represents a bound state, curve (c) a dissociative state and curve (b) a quasibound state. Such states are also referred to as [shape resonances](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_resonance#:%7E:text=A%20shape%20resonance%20is%20a,shape%20of%20a%20potential%20barrier.).

[image: a) bound state, b) quasibound state, c) dissociative state]

Comment: How can nuclear potentials (which are of Woods-Saxon type) have quasibound states? It does not seem to have a local and a global minimum. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [alpha decay](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/alptun.html).

Comment: You may also wanna look at the quasibound $A$ state of the helium molecule (i.e., helium excimer) as an interesting case. For a long time it was thought that the helium molecule should be in an excited state to physically exist without dissociation. It was in the 90s that a stable helium molecule in the ground state was detected.